# Using FarPoint Spreads in User Controls

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, spread, farpoint

i am using FarPoint Spreads in a Windows Forms Application.

To show a spread on several Forms, I created a user control which contains one of my spreads and manages the representation.

However the ActiveSheet Property of the Spread seems to always return the first sheet when my user control is not focused - no matter which sheet is actually selected.

Since the Spread still has the "correct" Sheet selected when the user control is out of focus, the information which was the last active spread has to be accessible somehow. Do you have any ideas how i can get (and modify) the active sheet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i called the constructor of the User Control multiple times on accident and thus was using the wrong references. The Properties work like desired - i was just showing the wrong control on my interface.